# Get the array index of duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

In a JavaScript array how can I get the index of duplicate strings?

Example:

```
MyArray = ["abc","def","abc"]; //----> return 0,2("abc");
```

Another example:

```
My Array = ["abc","def","abc","xyz","def","abc"] 
//----> return 0,2,5("abc") and 1,4("def");
```

I have no idea how to do this.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: traverse and collect, it's really not that hard. Don't be afraid to use loops.

Comment: `0,2,5("abc") and 1,4("def")` is not a valid return format and I could think of a number of details on how to return it. You should be more specific on what exactly you want to return.

Comment: Oh sorry, ("abc") and ("def") were only details of the return. I only want to return 0,2,5 and 1,4

Comment: You cannot return `0,2,5` *and* `1,4`, not without packing it into an object like in my answer. You could only return something like `0,1,2,4,5`, making it impossible to determine which entries they belong to or what entry is contained how often.

Comment: Addition: Or by using an iterator kind of pattern. But surely it's not what you want. This is exactly what I meant with my first comment: If you don't specify a valid return format, there are plenty of ways to do this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Update 01/2022*: It's not 2013 anymore, and many things have changed. I neither recommend modifying the prototype, nor is the approach in this answer the "best" as it requires several iterations over the array.

Here's an updated version of the original answer, retaining its spirit, as well as the original answer below.

```js
function getDuplicates<T>(input: T[]): Map<T, number[]> {
    return input.reduce((output, element, idx) => {
        const recordedDuplicates = output.get(element);
        if (recordedDuplicates) {
            output.set(element, [...recordedDuplicates, idx]);
        } else if (input.lastIndexOf(element) !== idx) {
            output.set(element, [idx]);
        }

        return output;
    }, new Map<T, number[]>());
}
```

---

Yet another approach:

```js
Array.prototype.getDuplicates = function () {
    var duplicates = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(duplicates.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
            duplicates[this[i]].push(i);
        } else if (this.lastIndexOf(this[i]) !== i) {
            duplicates[this[i]] = [i];
        }
    }

    return duplicates;
};
```

It returns an object where the keys are the duplicate entries and the values are an array with their indices, i.e.

```
["abc","def","abc"].getDuplicates() -> { "abc": [0, 2] }
```

Comment: Idea: Instead of using `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` in every iteration for every element, I would first check whether the element is already in `duplicates`. If it is you can directly push the index to the array. This saves some linear search time and you could even omit `indexOf` completely (just compare against `i`). Otherwise, using `lastIndexOf` is a nice approach!

Comment: I don't know why but i doesn't work...the result is [ object Object ]...and I don't have to return {"abc" : [0, 2]} but only [0, 2]...

Comment: You get `[object Object]` if you just output it like this. It's an object, you have to look at its properties! And no, you did *not* say you just want `[0,2]`. And that wouldn't make sense either, because what about your second example? How would you separate the indices for duplicates of different entries?

Comment: @user2695834: The default string representation of an object is `"[object Object]"`. So if you use `alert` or concatenate it with a string, that's what you get. You can then further process the object. You said you only need `[0,2]`, so just iterate over the object and get the value! I assume you have *some* basic knowledge of JavaScript. If not, I encourage you read a tutorial, such as http://eloquentjavascript.net/. Also have a look at the links in my answer.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Thank you a lot! Now it works! Sorry for my previous comment but I have only basic knowledges of Javascript. Thank you again Ingo Burk and Felix Kling! You saved me! :)

Comment: Done, I think. I'm new here.

Answer (score 4):

Another less sophisticated  approach:

Iterate over the whole array and keep track of the index of each element. For this we need a `string -> positions` map. An object is the usual data type to use for this. The keys are the elements of the array and the values are arrays of indexes/positions of each element in the array.

```
var map = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var element = arr[i];  // arr[i] is the element in the array at position i

    // if we haven't seen the element yet, 
    // we have to create a new entry in the map
    if (!map[element]) {
        map[element] = [i];
    }
    else {
       // otherwise append to the existing array
        map[element].push(i);
    }
    // the whole if - else statement can be shortend to
    // (map[element] || (map[element] = [])).push(i)
}
```

Now you can iterate over the map and remove all entries where the array value has a length of one. Those are elements that appear only once in an array:

```
for (var element in map) {
    if (map[element].length === 1) {
        delete map[element];
    }
}
```

Now `map` contains a `string -> positions` mapping of all duplicate elements of the array. For example, if you array is `["abc","def","abc","xyz","def","abc"]`, then `map` is an object of the form

```
var map = {
    'abc': [0,2,5],
    'def': [1,4]
};
```

and you can process it further in any way you like.

---

Further reading:

- [Eloquent JavaScript - Data structures: Objects and Arrays](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html)
- [MDN - Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
- [MDN - Predefined core objects, Array object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object)

Comment: one of the reasons to upvote is for your 510k, amazing

Answer (score 0):

This covers finding the indices efficiently:

```
var inputArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var encounteredIndices = {};

for(var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
  if (encounteredIndices[inputArray[i]])
    console.log(i); // Or add to some array if you wish
  else
    encounteredIndices[inputArray[i]] = 1;
```