# Javascript summarize duplicate and unique enteries of table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table 1 it has some following data right now which can be up-to 50-100 rows. I want to summarize information in it on the summarize button click and want to show it in an other table which will be created on the fly according to the summarized information. But I don't know how to do it.

[image]

I just simply want that if the code exists more than once than in output table all of its Sq-In should be added up. Like in the above table A1 is repeated three times so all its SqIn are added up and it gives A1 81.
Right now the id's of code's textbox are #code_0, #code_1,#code_2 and so on. where as the SqIn is #sqin_0, #sqin_1, #sqin_2 and so on...

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Codes</th>
            <th>room</th>
            <th>SqIn</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="A1" /></td>    
            <td><input type="text" value="1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="25"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>            
            <td><input type="text" value="B1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="25"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="C1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="25"/></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="A1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="2"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="25"/></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="B1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="25"/></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td><input type="text" value="C1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="2"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="25"/></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button id=summarise ">Summarise</button>

<table id="SummarizedTable">
//here the summary table should come.
</table>
```

JS

```
SqIn: +(element.childNodes[1].firstElementChild.value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In close to a psuedo code form, but it will look like below:

```
var myList = {};
$('input[id^="code"]').each(function(){    // Grab all input with ID begins with 'code'
    var myID = $(this).attr("id");         // Get the actual ID
    if( myList[myID] == '' ){              
        var value = 0;
        $('input').find('[id=' + myID + ']').each(function(){
            value += $(this).next().val(); // Get the all elements next to all 'id=myID'
        });
        myList[myID] = value;              // Insert the total
    }
});

for( var i in myList ){
    var id = i;
    var value = myList[i];
    // Draw the summary <td> using the id and the value here
}
```

Comment: Hi!Thanks for replying let me integrate it. In the Mean while Can u have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417728/get-the-array-index-of-duplicates) I am not getting how to read the `return duplicates` array:( Do u think it is helpful in my case ????

Comment: The returned object will be in a format of { "abc": [0, 2] }. It's a hashmap whose value is an array of the indices of the duplicates.

Comment: ok But I how read them :( . like in my case it should be {"A1":[0,5,6]} but how i will access it?

Comment: var myArray = duplicates['A1'];  // now you have an array

Comment: When i did `console.log(myArray)` the output comes is `[object Array]`

Comment: console.log(myArray.join(", "));

Comment: ok thanks. come to your code now. u wrote `value += $(this).next().val(); // Get the all elements next to all 'id=myID'
` I have actually 5 columns between Code and SqIn. Like
Code|Type|Room|Qty|Length|Depth|SqIn.
What i understand from ur comment is that it will get value of next column but what to do in this case.

Comment: $(this).siblings().find('[id^="sqin"]').val();

Comment: I put ur code as it is and `console.log(myID);` its giving all id's of the code field then i did `console.log(value);` in the `if` statement but :( get 0. please tell me what to do now. I am not good in scripting :(

Comment: Try to console.log(value) inside $('input').find('[id=' + myID + ']').each(function(){

Comment: also try to alter .val() to .html()

Comment: Is this `value += $(this).siblings().find('[id^="sqin"]').val();
` ok? because console.log(value) returns `0` before this statement but no answer of `console.log` after this statement

Comment: $(this).parent().siblings().find('[id^="sqin"]').val();

Comment: No problem..ok lets come to that link which i shared with u and u replied about accessing element. after doing hit and try i come up with this answer in console.`"0,5,6"` `"1,7"` "2,10"` '"3,8"` '"4,9"` and `"11"`. Its giving correct location of A1, B1,C1,D1,E1 and F1..but its not telling A1 is 0,5,6... any idea..???

Comment: what do you mean by "not telling A1 is 0,5,6"?

Comment: means that how i will come to know that `console.log(myArray.join(", "));` prints the value of A1. because by using this i can do one thing that is adding the sqin values by using those 0,5,6 #sqin_0+#sqin_5+#sqin_6..

Comment: I see. It appears that I misunderstood the condition of your problem. If you could post your code on JSfiddle, it will be much better for other folks to take a look. If not, I will check back in a few hours.

Comment: Anyhow, for the duplicates array, you should be able to do: for( var i in duplicates) { console.log( "element: " + i + " array: " + duplicates[i].join(", ") ); } to see the entire values.

Comment: Thanks. Now i am getting `"element: A1 array: 0, 5, 6"` now one more question can i pick 0,7,12 one by one, because i wana concatenate it with the #sqin_ id..??? so that i will be able to plus 25+30+23 and stores the answer in arr B[0].. and so on..
I tried to put it on jsfiddle but its giving error there array.getDuplicates(); is not a function. although its running at my end..

Comment: I did `console.log(i)` its printing A1,B1,C1,D1,E1 so i got the one column for the output. now i wana get the sum of sqin of each index like A1[0,5,6] add #sqin_0+#sqin_5+#sqin_6 . please tell me a way.. sorry for taking your this my time.. :(

Comment: Is there any way to get the indexes? like [0,5,6] one by one??

Comment: for( var i in duplicates ){ for( var j=0; j<duplicates[i].length; j++ ){ console.log( duplicates[i][j] ); } }

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an array to hold the cell information `var cells = [];`
2. Read in the cell information from the DOM and add each record to the array `cells.push({code: 'A1', SqIn: 25});`
3. Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to combine and sum the cell information in the array.
4. Empty your `tbody` from the `table`
5. Add the cells from the result of your `reduce` (3)

An example

CSS

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Codes</th>
            <th>SqIn</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="summarise">Summarise</button>
```

Javascript

```
function emptyNode(node) {
    while (node.firstChild) {
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
}

function summariseTable(tableId) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById(tableId).lastElementChild,
        reduced = Array.prototype.map.call(tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr'), function (element) {
            return {
                code: element.firstElementChild.textContent,
                SqIn: +(element.lastElementChild.textContent)
            };
        }).reduce(function (acc, rowData) {
            if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(rowData.code)) {
                acc[rowData.code] = rowData.SqIn;
            } else {
                acc[rowData.code] += rowData.SqIn;
            }

            return acc;
        }, {});

    emptyNode(tbody);
    Object.keys(reduced).forEach(function (code) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr'),
            tdCode = document.createElement('td'),
            tdSqIn = document.createElement('td');

        tdCode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
        tdSqIn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(reduced[code]));
        row.appendChild(tdCode);
        row.appendChild(tdSqIn);
        tbody.appendChild(row);
    });
}

document.getElementById('summarise').addEventListener('click', function () {
    summariseTable('myTable');
}, false);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/uqB77/)

This example replaces the content of the current table, but you can easily have it create a new table instead. If you have `input`s in the `td`s then get the `value` of those instead.

Comment: I have input tags inside the td. how to handle them. I have checkd ur answer its working fine.but what about the `input` :(

Comment: `SqIn: +(element.lastElementChild.textContent)` -> `SqIn: +(element.lastElementChild.firstElementChild.value)`

Comment: how to create the new table can u please tell me. thanks

Comment: one more thing. i have 6 columns between Code and SqIn but just want to summarize these two columns..

Comment: Not if your HTML looks like your example. Use the same methods that I have demonstrated in my example [`createEelement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

Comment: The make sure that you choose the correct cell `SqIn: +(element.childNode[7].firstElementChild.value)`

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to go and study the [`DOM`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference) for a while.

Comment: Ok i will study But right now i really don't have time to study. can u please help me ..?? [have a look at my actual example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/msq3kdudo3h6tp1/example.png)
actually i have a table and i want to create a new table on the fly on summarize button. the function is just like u did it in ur example.

Comment: More information about [`HTMLTableElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) and it's methods. Ok, you don't have six columns between them but five, so [`childNodes[6]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes) instead of `childNodes[7]`. Other than write your code for you, I have given you all the necessary information so you don't need to search.

Comment: ok. in ur jsfiddle i insert one column between Code and SqIn that is Room and did `SqIn: +(element.childNodes[2].firstElementChild.value)`
but its giving this in console `TypeError: element.childNodes[2].firstElementChild is undefined`

Comment: and in each `tr` there are three `td` having `input` in each cell

Comment: Where is the modified jsFiddle that you speak of?

Comment: just at the run time . i didnt modify it. i opened it run it did changes with input again run it was running fine when i insert new column and wrote `childNodes[2]` not working

Comment: can u have a look at the edited code with which i tried.

Comment: Yes, so where is this jsFiddle that you modified? There are clearly text nodes in the HTML, so use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) instead of `childNodes`. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/22DKb/

Comment: i dont know how to save the modified version in jsfiddle. i dont even have account there. Thanks for your reply but can u please tell me one more thing that is how to print the new table i dont want to refresh the actual one.

Comment: Get the element with the `id` of the summarised table. Add the appropriate elements using the methods defined in [`HTMLTableElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) or like I demonstrated using `createElement`, instead of emptying the original table's `tbody` and adding elements.

Comment: You also don't need a jsFiddle account, just hit the `update` button and the `URL` points at that saved version.

Comment: if u don't mind and u have time can u please share a jsfiddle link. I shall be very thankful you. Otherwise It's totally ok and thanks for your help and time.

Comment: can u have a quick view on this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/22DKb/3/) i want the summarized row to be print outside that table. but how..??

Comment: Yes, you haven't created a new table to which you would append the elements. Like I explained above, or that you have in your example HTML.

Comment: please confirm it is this the correct way [link](http://jsfiddle.net/22DKb/4/) :)

Comment: Well, you are redefining the variable `tbody` instead of reusing it, which is not particularly good, but otherwise it is working.

Comment: one more thing to ask :| that is i have to insert the summary table values in the database how i will do this. how i will access each element of that table? like A1,B1,C1 I have to further search prices of these code in DB and print in the next column respectively.

Comment: The data is already contained in the variable `reduced` -> `reduced.A1` has the summed value and so on. See[`Working with objects`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Ok But the html according to the output of the summarized table is` <tr><td>A1</td><td>50</td></tr>` how to get A1..?? I didnt get it..:(

Comment: Where `//emptyNode(tbody);` add after `console.log(reduced);` or to see `A1` specifically then `console.log(reduced.A1);` and look in the `console`

Comment: I did its printing `[object Object]`

Comment: ok thanks. can u have a look on this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/22DKb/8/) actually my codes are also in `input` tag and i have write them in the fiddle. its giving undefined and just adding all the rows :(

Comment: Change `code: element.firstElementChild.value,` just like you did for `SqIn` when added an `input`, so `code: element.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.value,`. You really need to read about the `DOM` and how to access it.

Comment: thanks:) I will surely read it InshaAllah. But right now asking u because don't have enough time to complete it :(

Comment: I have one more question I have basically `autocomplete` in first cell. Now what its doing is adding up all the rows and gives one rows and write undefine in code cell of summary table :(

Comment: I'm sorry but this is completely off topic now.

Comment: what should i do now..?? ;(

Comment: Create a new question that has all the details and is specifically for the problem that you are experiencing.

Comment: Well what's the reason that incase of autocomplete its not wokring although `<input style="width:90px" class="codeRule" id="code_' + id + '" name="code_' + id + '"/>` this input is used for autocomplete and have attached the function to it like this `example( "input#code_"+id).autocomplete({ })`